# Background not showing on whole div?

Tags: css

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

This is what I have achieved:
[image]

For some reason, the background won't show on the whole area.
The page is live at http://goo.gl/K17Fjs

```
<div id="overview">
<img src="images/home-layout_17.png" alt="">
<div id="overview-text">
<h1>Overview</h1>
<p>Salem Al Hajri is a Company, registered under Qatar law, providing services in building construction, maintenance and manpower supply.</p><p>The main business of the company is to provide well trained, experienced, dedicated and hard working workers to the client. We will mobilize the construction workforce you need, for long or short-term projects, anywhere in the Qatar. Our team of construction professionals offers a single-source solution for all of your construction-related needs whether its restoration, site preparation, a new facility or facility renovation, we have the experience and personnel to provide the highest quality... Read More.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
h1 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #53504a;
}
#overview {
background-color: #f6f6f6;
border: 1px solid #dbdada;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: 21px;
padding: 12px;
}
#overview img { float: left;}
#overview-text { float: left; width: 650px; padding-left: 12px}
```

Comment: try adding height:auto; float:left; to #overview

Comment: you must use `overflow:hidden` on ID `#overview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#overview` rule.

Also, learn about [*clearfix*](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you tell me what does this property do exactly?

Comment: @lakshkhamesra this problem occurs when you give `float` property and until you not clear the floating this kind of effect will appear. `overflow:hidden` is one of the option to clear the `float`in addition you can use `clearfix` method also.

Comment: In short, when all the children elements inside a container `float`, the parent collapses. More info here: http://css-tricks.com/containers-dont-clear-floats/

Answer (score 1):

Add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before ending `#overview` div i.e. right after `#overview-text` div.

This happens because you are using floated elements & not clearing them. Floated element height is not taken into account to calculate parents height unless you use `clear`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;`, `height: auto;` and a **width property** to **#overview**